# C#: Value not persisting in postback

Tags: c#, variables

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class expt2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    double result ;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            result = 0.0;
 protected void Chkbxbd_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Chkbxbd.Checked)
        {
            txtbxttl.Text = "" + 10000;
            result += double.Parse(txtbxttl.Text);

        }
        else
            result = result - 10000;


      }
    protected void Chkbxsfa_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Chkbxsfa.Checked)
        {
            txtbxttl.Text = "" + 15000;
            result += double.Parse(txtbxttl.Text);

        }
        else
            result = result - 15000;


    }
 protected void btnttl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbxttl.Text = "" + result;

    }
}
```

In this code the individual value for checkbox is ok but when the total is made it becomes 0.

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Please ask an actual question. Explain what is happening and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

result variable will not be preerved in numereous post backs because the nature of web application is state less so tore the result in a ViewState or Session variable as shown below.

```
    public partial class expt2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    double result ;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
              Session["result"] = 0.0;
    }
 protected void Chkbxbd_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Chkbxbd.Checked)
        {
            txtbxttl.Text = "" + 10000;

            result = double.Parse(Session["result"].ToString());
            result += double.Parse(txtbxttl.Text);

            Session["result"] = result;

        }
        else
        {
             result = double.Parse(Session["result"].ToString());
             result = result - 10000;
             Session["result"]= result;
        }



      }
    protected void Chkbxsfa_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Chkbxsfa.Checked)
        {
            txtbxttl.Text = "" + 15000;
            result = double.Parse(Session["result"].ToString());
            result += double.Parse(txtbxttl.Text);
            Session["result"] = result;

        }
        else
        {
            result = double.Parse(Session["result"].ToString());
            result = result - 15000;
            Session["result"] = result;
        }



    }
 protected void btnttl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbxttl.Text = "" + Session["result"].ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Friend for reply.
but whenever the post back does occur how does the value of result becomes 0.0 as it could get the value only when there is no post back

Answer (score 3):

The "result" value is not persisted through postbacks. Either recalculate it always when you need the final result or store it in the viewstate.

Comment: but whenever the post back does occur how does the value of result becomes 0.0 as it could get the value only when there is no post back

Comment: The default value of all number types is zero. In each postback, it starts with zero.